# How can I transfer bookmarks from an old computer that ran Windows?

Tags: bookmarks

I need to transfer my bookmarks from an old computer using a flash drive. Can someone give me the procedure for doing this properly?

I need to know how to transfer bookmarks from Windows to a flash drive and then add them to my Bookmarks menu in Firefox. My Windows computer used Firebox exclusively.

Comment: Firefox has the ability to [sync bookmarks, extensions, etc.](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/sync/). You might find that much more convenient than manual syncing.

Answer (score 3):

From the Mozilla Knowledge Base article “[Export Firefox bookmarks to an HTML file to back up or transfer bookmarks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer)”:

> This article explains how to export your bookmarks to an HTML file,
>   which can be used as a backup or for importing into another web
>   browser.
>
> 1. Click the Bookmarks button on the right side of the navigation toolbar. On the menu bar, click <kbd>Bookmarks</kbd>. At the top of
>      the Firefox window, click the <kbd>Bookmarks</kbd> menu and select
>      <kbd>Show All Bookmarks</kbd> to open the Library window.
>
>    Click the Bookmarks button and select <kbd>Show All Bookmarks</kbd> to open the Library window.
> 2. From the toolbar on the Library window, click <kbd>Import and Backup</kbd> and choose <kbd>Export Bookmarks to HTML...</kbd>.
> 3. In the Export Bookmarks File window that opens, choose a location to save the file, which is named `bookmarks.html` by default. The
>      desktop is usually a good spot, but any place that is easy to remember
>      will work.
> 4. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button. The Export Bookmarks File window will close.
> 5. Close the Library window.
>
> *Your bookmarks are now successfully exported from Firefox. The bookmarks HTML file you saved is now ready to be imported into another
>   web browser.*

Answer (score 0):

**Export** the Firefox **Bookmarks** :

In Firefox menu click Bookmarks.
Click Show All Bookmarks.
Click Import and Backup.
Click Export Bookmarks to HTML.
Choose a location and save the file.

**Import** the Firefox **Bookmarks** :

In Firefox menu click Bookmarks.
Click Show All Bookmarks.
Click Import and Backup.
Click Import Bookmarks from HTML.
Choose the file you had saved before.

[image: firefox-bookmarks]